# Wann verwendet man „zu“ mit dem Infinitiv?

Tags: verb, preposition, sentence-structure

Wie kann man wissen, ob man den Infinitiv mit oder ohne „zu“ schreibt?

- Das darf ich nicht probieren.
- Das wage ich nicht zu probieren.
- Ich gehe spazieren.
- Ich mag es zu spazieren.

Bonusfrage: Was für eine Wortart ist dieses „zu“

Comment: Wir sind gekommen um zu bleiben. Ich mage es, spazieren zu gehen.

Comment: I found this website very useful on this question:
https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/use-of-zu-and-um-zu/ in fact https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com is a really good resource, full-stop. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Grundsätzlich wird der Infinitiv mit "zu" gebildet; "zu" steht hier als Konjunktion. Ausnahmen sind z. B.:

- die Modalverben dürfen, können, mögen, müssen, sollen, wollen;
- hören, sehen, fühlen, spüren ("ich höre ihn reden", "ich sehe sie gehen").

[canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Infinitiv.html#Anchor-Reiner-47857) hat eine sehr schöne Zusammenstellung der Ausnahmen.

Übrigens: Das Modalverb "mögen" wird im Deutschen wahrscheinlich seltener genutzt als das englische "to like". Die Konstruktion mit "mögen" klingt häufig umständlicher und sogar unbeholfener als die Nutzung des Adverbs "gern" oder "gerne":

> "ich gehe gerne spazieren"

halte ich auf jeden Fall für besser als die Formulierung mit "mögen". Die Übersetzung von "to like" mit "mögen" ist zwar zutreffend, aber nicht unbedingt die stilistisch beste Lösung.

Comment: Die canoo-Seite ist sehr hilfvoll!

Comment: +1 für den Gebrauch von _gerne_ statt _mögen_.

Comment: Bzgl. Modalverben: Das gilt aber nur, wenn sie auch als Modalverben gebraucht werden. Auch: wenn der Infinitiv Teil eines Nebensatzes ist, z.B. `Ich mag es nicht, darüber zu reden.`

Comment: @Tim: die richtige Übersetzung für *helpful* ist *hilfreich*. (Verbessere nur, weil du in deinem Profil darum bittest.)

Comment: @Rasmus: Danke schön! Peinlich; ich habe oft "hilfvoll" gesagt.

Answer (score 6):

**Infinitiv ohne "zu":**

- nach Modalverben: wir sollen kommen.
- nach "lassen", "machen": Lasset die Kindlein zu mir kommen.
- nach "machen": "Ein fahrender Scholast! der Kasus macht mich lachen "(Goethe, Faust)
- nach "hören", "sehen": ich  sah sie kommen.
- nach "bleiben": bleib sitzen!
- nach "gehen": (dein Beispiel) ich gehe spazieren.
- Infinitiv als Imperativ: Grammatikbücher nicht vergessen!

**Faustregel**

In allen anderen Fällen "zu" verwenden! [der vorige Satz illustriert übrigens den  Infinitiv als Imperativ...] Es gibt gewiss Gegenbeispiele, aber statistisch gesehen wirst Du viele Fehler vermeiden, indem Du diesen einfachen Regeln folgst.

Comment: Ich bin gekommen, die Monroe zu sehen, die Callas zu hören, das Filet zu essen, die Susi zu ... - aber sie war nicht da.

Comment: Ich denke, dass in diesem Fall die Infinitivkonjunktion "zu" unausgeschprochen bleibt. Es ist in jedem Fall kein Gegenbeispiel zu meiner Faustregel: Tim kann ruhig sagen "Ich bin gekommen, *um* die Monroe zu sehen" usw.

Comment: could be that a good rule of thumbs is: 1. no `zu` after modal verbs. 2 if the English translation has no `to` then the German have no `zu` ?

Answer (score 4):

**ZU + infinitive**:

- As a complement to verbs like: beginnen, anfangen, aufhören, hoffen, lernen, vergessen, etc.

> Es fängt an zu regnen.
>
> Ich höre auf zu studieren.
>
> Ich habe vergessen, dich anzurufen.

- As a complement of constructions like: Lust haben, Zeit haben, Spaß machen, etc.

> Hast du Lust, einen Stadtbummel zu machen?
>
> Hast du heute Abend Zeit, mit mir ins Kino zu gehen?

- As a complement of adjectives like: dumm, einfach, schön, wichtig, etc.

> Es ist schön, wieder in Deutschland zu sein!
>
> Es ist einfach, Deutsch zu lernen!

---

**EDIT**: (I'd like to complete this answer)

- Zu jmndm. sprechen
- Zu Bett (schlafen) gehen
- jmdn. zu Tisch laden/bitten
- jmdm., einem Mißstand zu Leibe gehen
- zu einem Ball, Fest, Geburtstag, Begräbnis gehen
- von ... zu

> von Haus zu Haus, von Tür zu Tür gehen

- von Pontius zu Pilatus laufen
- von Stufe zu Stufe
- von Station zu Station (=auf jeder Station) wurde der Zug voller
- gibt an, daß eine Sache einer anderen hinzugefügt wird

> die Zeitung zu den anderen legen

- jmd., etw. befindet sich an einem bestimmten Ort, in einer bestimmten Lage

> zu Hause sein, bleiben / krank zu Bett liegen

Comment: I understand most of these cases, butn ot the first. How do I know _which_ verbs are like _beginnen_, _anfangen_ et.c? Why _wagen_ but not _dürfen_?

Comment: @tohu: What about _gehen_, as in _ich gehe spazieren_? Edit: Never mind, I just saw your list of exceptions.

Comment: @Tim N - no worries - i've removed my comment...

Comment: @Tim N: the first case is "Infinitive with complements as subject of the sentence".

Comment: The EDIT does not complete the answer as this is not related to verbs or the Infinitiv at all.