# “Du hast da noch ein Bier zu stehen” - richtig oder falsch?

Tags: preposition, infinitive

In Berlin und Umgebung ist es üblich, Infinitive mit “zu” zu versehen, wenn es darum geht, einen Zustand bzw. eine aktuelle Lage zu beschreiben, etwa wie:

> - “du hast deinen Taschenrechner noch bei mir zu liegen”
> - “wenn Sie dort also die Summenformel zu stehen haben [...]”

Ist das richtig? Ich kenne es nur ohne zu, aber mittlerweile bin ich verwirrt, ob das nicht vielleicht doch richtig ist - und ohne “zu” falsch. Insbesondere da es ja auch bspw. 
“ich bin gekommen um zu bleiben” oder “ich mag es zu schlafen” heißt.

Was ist richtig? Ist es eine allgemeine Regel im Deutschen immer ein “zu” zu gebrauchen, wenn es um Infinitive geht?

Comment: Die Beispiele hören sich für mich falsch an - Ich komme aus dem Südwesten Deutschlands.

Comment: Verwandte Frage: [Wann verwendet man „zu“ mit dem Infinitiv?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1591/266) die aber keinen Bezug zur Berliner Mundart hat.

Comment: "Man kann zwar auch in Berlin gepflegt einen sitzen haben, aber man hat niemanden zu sitzen, und man hat auch niemanden zu liegen. Folglich muss kein Mann befürchten, jemals von seiner Frau die folgenden Worte zu hören: "Schatz, du kannst da jetzt nicht rein, ich hab da noch den Klempner zu liegen." -- [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,528579,00.html) :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[image: Karte für "zu stehen haben"]

Die Berliner und Brandenburger (in Teilen auch die Menschen in Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, Niedersachsen und Sachsen-Anhalt) gehen mit der Konstruktion "zu stehen haben" (wobei "stehen" auch durch andere Infinitive ersetzt werden kann) definitiv einen Sonderweg, wie die [Karte](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde_7/f13a/) aus dem genialen [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) zeigt. Im Netz habe ich an [zwei](http://forumhochbegabung.siteboard.org/f23t1128-quot-angst-vor-der-angst-quot.html?start=40) [Stellen](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article467863.html) die schöne Formulierung "Brandenburgischer Infinitiv" gefunden. In einem [Forum](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/7981/sbj/erweiteter-infinitiv-mit-zu/) wird das Duden-Nachschlagewerk ["Richtiges und gutes Deutsch"](http://www.duden.de/aktuelle_meldungen/richtiges-und-gutes-deutsch-schreiben-und-sprechen) in der 5. Auflage (2001) unter "stehen" wie folgt zitiert:

> [...] etwas zu stehen haben: Der Gebrauch der Infinitivkonjunktion *zu* bei *stehen* in diesen mit *haben* gebildeten Fügungen ist **landschaftlich (Berlin)** und gilt **standardsprachlich als falsch**: Sie hat einen schönen alten Schrank in ihrem Zimmer *stehen* (nicht: *zu stehen*). [...]

und noch deutlicher unter "zu":

> [...] Die Infinitivkonjunktion *zu* bei den Verben *liegen, stehen, wohnen* usw. (etwas im Keller *zu liegen, zu stehen haben*): Der Gebrauch von *zu* bei den Verben *liegen, stehen, wohnen* usw., wenn sie mit *haben* das Prädikat bilden, ist **landschaftlich** und gilt **standardsprachlich als nicht korrekt**. Er kommt vor allem in Berlin und in Niedersachsen vor. Es muss also heißen: Er hatte dreitausend Mark auf der Bank *liegen* (nicht: *zu liegen*). Wir haben unsere Mutter bei uns *wohnen* (nicht: *zu wohnen*). Korrekt ist natürlich die Verwendung von *zu* zusammen mit *haben* dann, wenn eine **Aufgabe oder Notwendigkeit** ausgedrückt wird: Sie hatte viel *zu tragen* (= musste viel tragen). Du hast *zu schweigen* (= musst schweigen). [...]

(Hervorhebungen jeweils von mir)

Ich gehe also davon aus, dass Du mit dieser Formulierung im mündlichen Sprachgebrauch in Brandenburg und angrenzenden Gebieten nicht weiter auffällst, anderswo aber irritierte Blicke ernten wirst, auch wenn man Dich wohl verstehen wird. Im Schriftlichen würde ich solche Formulierungen allgemein eher nicht benutzen.

Comment: ...ich nutze "zu stehen" übrigens ab und an auch ganz gerne. Ich mag die irritierten Blicke ;-)

Comment: [Die Ärzte](http://www.bademeister.com) - [Westerland (To the Max)](http://www.lyricsvip.com/Die-%C3%84rzte/Westerland-(To-the-Max)-Lyrics.html): "[...] Ich kann jeden Abend Schampus saufen, denn auf St. Pauli hab ich Pferdchen **zu laufen**. [...]". Und die sind ja aus Berlin (aus Berlin!).

Comment: Ich würde auch sagen *zu stehen*, aber nur in bestimmten Kontext: *Bitte setzen Sie sich doch. - Nein, danke. Ich bevorzuge es, zu stehen.*

Comment: @Em1: das würde ich auch sagen. Hat aber nix mit der Konstruktion hier zu tun ;-)

Comment: die Konstruktion, um die es hier geht, findet sich auch in dem Ausdruck
"ein Ding zu laufen haben". Das ist m.E. durchaus eine verselbständigte, stehende Formulierung -- zum einen natürlich in. o.g. Region, aber auch in "seriöser" Literatur aus renommierten Häusern:
_Großvater hatte ein Ding zu laufen. Dass er sich das im KZ weggeholt hatte, wusste ich damals noch nicht. Jedenfalls ließ er an dem Ding, das er zu laufen hatte, alle teilhaben, und so hatte auch Großmutter bald ein Ding zu laufen._ (B. Voss: "Drei Irre...", 2013, Hoffmann&Campe)

Answer (score 4):

> - Du hast da noch ein Bier stehen
> - Wir haben noch ein Bier zu verkaufen

Man findet für jeden Infinitiv eine Bildung mit *zu*, behaupte ich keck:

> Wir haben keine Lust in der zweiten Reihe zu stehen

denn mein Deutschlehrer piesackte uns seinerseits mit einem monotonen "laufen und zu laufen", "schlafen und zu schlafen", "Xen und zu Xen" sobald es um den Infinitiv ging. Daraus folgt freilich nicht, dass man überall das *zu* nach Belieben bringen oder weglassen kann.

*Ein Bier noch zu stehen haben*, um nicht zu sagen *ein Bier noch zu stehen zu haben*, ist Mundart - ansonsten falsch.

Richtig natürlich ist:

> Sie ist noch zu haben.

Comment: Gibt es eine grammatische Regel dafür wann man “zu” verwendet und wann nicht?

Comment: Siehe den Link unter Deiner Frage.

Comment: Mein Deutschlehrer sagte immer: "Wer brauchen ohne zu gebraucht ist zu gar nichts zu gebrauchen."

Comment: Hätte er nicht sagen brauchen.