# Wann wird der Infinitiv mit "zu" verwendet?

Tags: infinitive

Heute habe ich eine Nachricht geschrieben und habe dazu eine Frage. Wann verwendet man "zu" mit dem Infinitiv?
Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> Ich habe schon zweimal zu zahlen versucht.
>   Ich habe schon zweimal zahlen versucht.

Comment: Related: [Wann verwendet man „zu“ mit dem Infinitiv?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1591/9551)

Comment: Titel war zwar in Englisch, der Rest der Frage in Deutsch. Dies ist recht ungünstig. Habe der Frage nun einen deutschen Titel verpasst, die Frage grammatisch ein wenig überarbeitet. Alles in allem aber ein Duplikat.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean "to pay" when saying "zahlen"?
Then I'd write the following:

```
Ich habe schon 2 mal versucht zu bezahlen.
```